# Can we do without [wordpad]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[wordpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpad) got its wiki today. That's how I noticed that this tag even exists. But is it really useful? I looked at the 17 questions of the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpad):

- five times wordpad is used as viewer/editor for RTF files,
- three times to view/edit other files with [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668048/opening-a-wordpad-txt-file-with-c) or [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135557/errors-in-building-a-rss-xml-in-windows-using-word-pad) success,
- building a clone or using icons accounts for another 3 questions,
- one seems to me off topic because it's about [removing wordpad from an OS image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851531/windows-ce-6-wordpad-replacement)
- two mainly about the `TFontDialog` and the `TRichEdit` control, the last one highly upvoted.

and then there are

- two questions about [controlling wordpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094353/c-sharp-how-can-i-get-a-text-range-from-wordpad-by-sending-the-em-gettextrange) [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343755/controlling-wordpad-in-windows-using-messages),
- and only one user mentioned [using wordpad for checking out source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232253/how-to-set-wordpads-default-plain-text-font).

Most of those questions will do as well without [wordpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpad). Does it make sense to keep this tag?

Comment: Well we do have [vim] and [emacs]...

Comment: It has 17 questions, so it won't be that difficult to remove if we agree that it should be.

Comment: @user000001 Those are highly configurable, even programmable and used by a lot of programmers. I know that wordpad is a highly available editor but is it a relevant one in programming related questions?

Comment: @AstroCB That's my point. **If** we agree ...

Comment: They are all programming questions.  Wordpad is the stand-alone version of the RichTextBox control.  With a twist, the kind that gets programmers in trouble.  The tag is relevant and completely harmless.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, that's a good reason to keep this tag. Your second sentence could make its way into the wiki.